# GORM: how to point FK from child to parent?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Here's the scenario: questions and answers. A question can exists without an answer but (obviously) an answer must point back to a question. I'd like to be able to fetch a question and left join against the answer. Basic stuff but I can't work out how to achieve this in GORM.

I have two structs:

```
type Question struct {
  Tenancy string `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  ID      string `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  Text    string
  ...
}

type Answer struct {
  Tenancy string `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  ID      string `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  Text    string
  ...
}
```

I'd like to achieve something like:

```
type Question struct {
  Tenancy string
  ID      string
  Text    string
  Answer  *Answer // Optional answer - left join
  ...
}

type Answer struct {
  Tenancy string
  ID      string
  Text    string
  ...
}
```

I have composite primary keys on both question and answer and ideally I'd like a foreign key constraint between the two i.e. `(tenancy, id) references questions(tenancy, id)` then be able to execute something like

`db.Joins("Answer").First(&question)`

If necessary I can add an additional `QuestionID` field on the `Answer` but I still can't work out how to setup the FKs correctly. For example this works:

```
type Question struct {
  Tenancy string
  ID      string
  Text    string
  ...
}

type Answer struct {
  Tenancy    string
  ID         string
  QuestionID string   `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
  Question   Question `gorm:"foreignKey:Tenancy,QuestionID;references:Tenancy,ID"`
  Text       string
  ...
}
```

Which allows me to fetch answers with questions but I want it the other way round, questions with (nullable) answers.

If I try to add an `Answer` field on the `Question` the migration blows up:

invalid field found for struct Question's field Answer: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was over complicating things:

```
type Question struct {
  Tenancy string  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  ID      string  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  Text    string  `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
  Answer  *Answer `gorm:"foreignKey:Tenancy,ID;references:Tenancy,ID"`
  ...
}

type Answer struct {
  Tenancy  string  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  ID       string  `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:false"`
  Text     string  `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
  ...
}
```

Generates the correct foreign keys